# How is international law interpreted when the set of states is subjective?

Tags: international

Different states recognize different other enteties as states, or consider them to be non-states. Sometimes there is international disagreement over which purported government for a state is the real one. See for example cases like Taiwan, Ukraine, the Houthis in Yemen, and even Israel who IIRC is still not universally recognized.

But international law also defines certain things, such as, IIRC, blockading "your" territorial waters, as legal for states to do but illegal for non-states.

In the absence of consensus over who actually is a state, aren't the conclusions of what actions were legal or illegal under international law also going to diverge for different interpreters?

Or do the countries that recognize poorly-recognized states or hold out on recognizing well-recognized states agree to treat them the more commonly accepted way when working with international law?

Or do countries routinely completely disagree on the conclusions from international law, but in cases where that happens it doesn't practically matter because the countries in question are sufficiently hostile and international law is sufficiently unenforced?

Comment: Well yes, most of the time everyone agrees that a given thing is or isn't a state. But I'm asking about the edge cases, which are more likely to give rise to disputes anyway.

Answer (score 3):

International law is either *customary* law or created through treaties binding only the participants.

There are some treaties which bind *signatories* to treat *non-signatory states* in certain ways, provided the non-signatories follow certain rules. I'm thinking about rules of war here, and their definitions of combatants. But mostly, it is a question of custom. If a state is recognized by *most* other states, even the few who do not recognize it may be compelled by international consensus to treat that state as de-facto legitimate.

Consider the early Cold War, and the West German attempt at the [Hallstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hallstein_Doctrine) doctrine (no FRG relations with countries which recognized the GDR) and how that ended -- the FRG accepted reality in practice, while maintaining the legal position that there was only one Germany, waiting to be [reunified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_reunification).